# Advanced Installer Outlook Add-in VSTO MSI Package

Tags: windows-installer, outlook-addin, sccm, advanced-installer

I'm creating msi package of my Outlook Desktop Addin, using VSTO add-in msi package feature of advanced installer. (Method: link)

Once installed through SCCM (mass-deployment), for it to appear on outlook desktop application, I need client outlook desktop application to restart. Or, if this is not possible, I would like to prompt user to restart their systems.

This configuration is nowhere to be found when I'm creating the MSI. Please guide me through this. If this is achievable through (MSI+SCCM) combination for mass deployment.

Comment: Is it necessary that the installer restarts outlook? It should be fairly easy to close outlook, much harder to start it again (i.e. start it with the correct user). I would just close it and let the user start it again if he needs it, is that an option?

Comment: That would appear to the user as if outlook has crashed. For a big organization, it won't be feasible.

Comment: You could inform the user about the closing. I don't want to argue for this approach I just have concerns that as outlook is running as user and your installer is running as system there is no great way to restart a program without the owner changing (there is the hack of creating a scheduled task 1min in the future but I would not call that feasible...) so I kinda fear you might need to compromise somewhere. You can of course restart the whole pc it is just a lot more disruptive so I wouldn't recommend it but sccm supports it, even with notifications. Do you want an answer in that direction?

Comment: @Syberdoor I'm really not sure. If restarting outlook is not possible in a smooth way, I think it would be OK to prompt users to restart their systems. However, I'm unable to do too that with my current knowledge. If there is a way to prompt users for the restart using SCCM, it would be great.

Comment: I still think by far the most user friendly, least disruptive and still not hacky option would just be to have a popup "Outlook has to be closed" (maybe with timer) and then let the user reopen but in case you really want sccm to handle the reboot I posted an answer on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I am not to handy when it comes to SCCM (you can try to search and see if there is any client restart setting available in the SCCM version you are using), but in what regards to the setup package you can try configuring it to trigger a computer restart after installation is done.

In Advanced Installer such reboot setting can be configured in Install Parameters view. There is a Reboot Behavior dropdown option you can set it to force reboot value.

Comment: This setting is present for normal softwares, when being packaged. For outlook add-ins, there is no such setting to restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the SCCM to handle your reboots these are your options:

In general SCCM supports two models of installation package/program and application and they allow for different settings regarding restart.

If you use a program there is an option called **"After running"** in the properties, which you can set to **"Configuration Manager restarts computer"** (in your case "Configuration Manager logs of user" might even be enough). Problems with this method can be that it will lead to **every** installation restarting even if outlook was not even started. Also the actual time for a reboot is per system and not per setup and is configured in the so called Client Settings (found under Administration --> Client Settings in the SCCM Console. The setting is called "Computer Restart" and allows for a time for the first warning and a different one for a permanent one)

If you use an application you can find the setting in the properties of your deployment type in the User Experience tab. It is called **"Should Configuration Manager enforce specific behavior regardless of the application's intended behavior?"** and can be set to **"Configuration Manager client will force a mandatory device restart"** to get the same behavior as with a program. However applications allow for a different more subtle approach as well. You can use the setting "Determine behavior based on return codes" (which is the default anyway). If your installer returns 3010 or 1641 this will trigger sccm to automatically trigger the reboot window (you can also define additional return codes and their behavior in the "Return Codes" tab). This allows you to write your application in a way that a reboot is only triggered when the application needs it (at least if your application can produce different return codes for different scenarios). The time for the reboot is defined by the same setting as for a program so no difference there.